# UJS + Bootstrap button loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's button loading state with Rails Unobtrusive JavaScript
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

The form element uses `data-remote="true"` option and returns a .js file.
The submit button calls `.button("loading")`, using the following JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-loading", function() {
  var btn;
  btn = $(this);
  btn.button("loading");
});
```

Is there a way to detect Ajax Success & Error conditions and reset the button state?

I tried to do something like below, but after this function is triggered, I can't figure out how to access the `.btn-loading` element that's active

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
  var btn;
  btn = $(this);  //how to access .btn-loading() that's active?
  btn.button("reset");
  btn.button("toggle");
});
```

Any suggestions on how to reset the button after ajax request?

Also, how do I detect HTML5 error and reset the button state?

UPDATE: Aug 14, 2012

I turns out you can listen to the event and trigger the button via:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", "form[data-remote]", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
  var el;
  el = $(this).find('.btn-loading');
  el.button("reset");
  el.button("toggle");
});
```

See this wiki: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

However, the error catching portion isn't working, anyone had success on this?

```
$("form").live("ajax:aborted:required", function(evt, elements) {
  var el;
  el = $(this).find('.btn-loading');
  el.button("reset");
  el.button("toggle");
});
```

Comment: where are you making the actual ajax request? That's where you need to add the callback to reset the button state.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm using Rails 3's Unobtrusive JavaScript's data-remote="true" in my form, which automatically converts any form to an ajax call. Hence I don't think I can call the $.ajax() specifically and know which DOM element was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works without any JavaScript

```
<form ... data-remote="true">
   ...
   <input class="btn" data-disable-with="Disabling text" name="commit" type="submit" value="Initial text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [jquery docs on `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (which go for event handling in general), they note that `this` in the handler function refers to the *DOM element that the **handler** was bound to*, NOT the element that originated the event.  So the easiest thing to do is to give all the loading buttons a common class (let's call it "ajax-button" for this example), bind your success handler to that and then you'll have the appropriate `this` available within your handler function.

If you were using jquery (assuming you have some function `resetButton` that does whatever resetting you want to do), you would just use something like the following to do the resetting.

```
$(".ajax-button").bind("ajax:success", function() { 
     $(this).button("reset").button("toggle");})
```

[This tutorial on Unobtrusive Javascript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) has some good additional information specific to Rails

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Basically bind the `click()` event to your `button`, and it will immediately show the loading state.  Then put the AJAX request together using your **URL**, **HTTP method** (`POST` or `GET`) and the **DataType** (in this case I used `JSON`).  jQuery provides `success` and `error` functions in the AJAX settings. Perform your app-specific logic on the button or whatever else applicable in the appropriate section.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$("#yourbutton",).on("click", function() {
   var btn;
   btn = $(this);
   btn.button("loading");
$.ajax({
    url: yoururl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     *perform error here*
    btn.button("failure");
    }
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    *perform success here - for you it seems to be*
    btn.button("reset");
    btn.button("toggle");
    }
});    
});
```

If you want to break it down to be generic for any button pressed, then you may try this.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-loading", function() {
doSomething($(this));
});
function doSomething(btn){
$.ajax({
    url: yoururl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     *perform error here* 
    btn.button("failure");
    }
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    *perform success here - for you it seems to be*
    btn.button("reset");
    btn.button("toggle");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks blasteralfred, I'm using Rails 3's Unobtrusive JavaScript's data-remote="true" in my form, which automatically converts any form to an ajax call. Hence I don't think I can call the $.ajax() specifically and maintain knowledge of which DOM element was clicked.